# How to make CKEDITOR display text in html

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I just changed my editor on my website from a regular decade old bbcode editor to the newest ckeditor. Everything works fine, expect that once a comment is submitted with CKeditor, the output is displayed like

```
<p>Testing</p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

So in the end the output displays the html code. How would I make it not display the html code and actually do what the html specifies, for example bold lettering, italics, centering etc..

By the way I am new to website development so be as simple as possible with an explanation or else I might not understand what you are talking about. I also added the code that I am working with below.

```
<?php

session_start();

include "init.php";

$pg_title = "Comments";

if($_SESSION['auth'] && $_SESSION['auth']['ip_address'] == ip2long(get_real_ip()) && isset($_SESSION['auth']['sid']))
{
    include ROOT . '/templates/' . $config['template_version'] . '/files/header.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $pg = $_GET['pg'];

    if(!preg_match("/[0-9]+/", ($id or $pg)))
    {
        echo '<div style="text-align: center;">The news ID or page number cannot be found in our database.</div>';
        include ROOT . '/templates/' . $config['template_version'] . '/files/footer.php';
        exit();
    }

    if(!isset($id) or !isset($pg) or empty($id) or empty($pg))
    {
        echo '<div style="text-align: center;">The news ID or page number cannot be found in our database.</div>';
        include ROOT . '/templates/' . $config['template_version'] . '/files/footer.php';
        exit();
    }

    $sql = mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'], $config['mysql_user'], $config['mysql_pass']);
    mysql_select_db($config['mysql_name'], $sql);

    $news = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$id'"));

    $limit = 20;
    $comment_num = $news['comments'];
    $pages_num = ceil($comment_num/$limit);
    $comments = "(<strong>$comment_num</strong>)";

    if($pages_num == 0) {
        $comments = "<a href=\"comments,".$news[0].",1.html\">$comments</a>";
    } else {
        $comments = "<a href=\"comments,".$news[0].",$pages_num.html\">$comments</a>";
    }
?>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="main">
                    <h2><?php echo stripslashes($news[1]); ?></h2>
                    <p><span>Posted by:</span> <?php echo "<a href=\"profile,".strtolower($news[2]).".html\">".ucwords($news[2])."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>On:</span> ".$news[4].""; ?></p>

                </div>
                <div class="comment"><?php echo $comments; ?></div>
                <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <p><?php echo stripslashes($news[3]); ?></p>

            </div>
        </div>



<?php

    $limit_value = $pg * $limit - ($limit);

    $comment_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE news_id = '$id' LIMIT $limit_value, $limit");

    if(mysql_num_rows($comment_list) == 0) {
            echo '<div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;"><em>No comments have been posted yet.</em></div>';
            //  echo "<div style=\"height: 1px; background: url('http://localhost/projects/bleachexile.com/templates/v3/images/split.gif') repeat-x bottom left; margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;\"></div>";
    }
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; border-collapse: collapse; }
.bbcode a { margin-left: 5px; padding: 0; float: left; border: 1px solid #242424; line-height: 0; }
.bbcode a:hover { background-color: #242424; border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; }
.bbcode a img { border: 0; }
.spoiler { width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; visibility: hidden; cursor: default; cursor: hand; }
.spoiler div { visibility: visible; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; background-color: #242424; font-weight: bold; }
.code { margin: 10px 5px; font-family: Courier New; }
-->
</style>
    <?php

    $timenow = time();

    $cc = ceil(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE news_id = '$id'"))/20);

    if(mysql_num_rows($comment_list) != 0)
    {
        echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; background: #242424; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
              <div style="float: right; margin-top: 3px;">Current Page: '.$pg.' of '.$cc.'</div>';
        echo "<form name=\"pageForm\" method=\"get\" action=\"\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\">Go to page: <select name=\"pg\" onchange=\"document.location=this.value\" style='width: 40px;'>";

        for($i = 1; $i <= $cc; $i++)
        {
            if($i == $pg) {
                echo "<option value=\"comments,$id,$i.html\" selected=\"selected\">$i</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value=\"comments,$id,$i.html\">$i</option>";
            }
        }

        echo "</select> of $cc</form>";

        echo '</div>';

    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comment_list))
    {
        $x = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$row['poster']}'"));

        if($x['active'] < ($timenow - 300))
        {
            $y = '<strong style="color: red;">Offline</strong>';
        }
        else
        {
            $y = '<strong style="color: green;">Online</strong>';
        }

        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="margin-bottom: 12px;">';
        echo '<tr>';
        ?><td align="center" valign="top" width="1%" style="padding: 2px;">
<?php
$ava = explode("|", $x['user_avatar']);
if($ava[0] == "local")
{
    $img = getimagesize(ROOT . "/images/uploads/avatars/".strtolower($x['username']).$ava[1]."");
    echo '<img src="images/uploads/avatars/' . strtolower($x['username']) . $ava[1] . '" width="'.$img[0].'" height="'.$img[1].'" alt="'.ucwords($x['username']).'\'s Avatar" />';
}
else
{
    echo '<img src="templates/v3/images/no_avatar.gif" width="75" height="75" alt="No Avatar" />';
}
    echo "<div style='margin-top: -2px; text-align: center;'>";
      if ($x['custom_rank'] == NULL) {
        if($x['posts'] <= 200 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Human";
        } elseif($x['posts'] > 200 and $x['posts'] <= 500 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Student Exorcist";
        } elseif($x['posts'] > 500 and $x['posts'] <= 700 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Novice Exorcist";
        } elseif($x['posts'] > 700 and $x['posts'] <= 800 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Advanced Exorcist";
        } elseif($x['posts'] > 800 and $x['posts'] <= 900 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Equip Type Exorcist";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  900 and $x['posts'] <= 1000 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Parasite Type Exorcist";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  1000 and $x['posts'] <= 1200 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Division Leader";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  1200 and $x['posts'] <= 1500 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "General";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  1500 and $x['posts'] <= 1800 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Akuma";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  1800 and $x['posts'] <= 2000 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Akuma Level 2";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  2000 and $x['posts'] <= 2500 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Akuma Level 3";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  2500 and $x['posts'] <= 3500 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Akuma Level 4";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  3500 and $x['posts'] <= 4500 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Noah Family Member";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  4500 and $x['posts'] <= 5000 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "S-Class Missing-nin";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  5000 and $x['posts'] <= 6000 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Legendary Sannin";
        } elseif($x['posts'] >  6000 and $x['posts'] <= 8000 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Kage";
        } elseif($x['posts'] > 8001 and $x['rank'] != "1") {
            echo "Hokage";
        } elseif($x['rank'] == "1") {
            echo "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: royalblue;'>Administrator</span>";
        }
      } else {
        echo '<span style="color: maroon;">'.$x['custom_rank'].'</span>';
        if($x['rank'] == "1") {
            echo "<br /><span style='font-weight: bold; color: royalblue;'>Administrator</span>";
        }
      }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
    echo "<strong>Posts:</strong> " . $x['posts'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<td align="left" valign="top" style="background: #242424;"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e; background: #323232;"><div style="padding: 2px;">Posted by <strong><a href="profile,'.strtolower($row['poster']).'.html">'.ucwords($row['poster']).'</a></strong> on '.$row['date'].'</div></div><div style="padding: 2px;">'.stripslashes($row['comment']).'</div></td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';                                                                                                                 // comments,'.$id.','.$pg.','.$row['id'].'.html
        if($x['donor'] == 1 or $x['referrals'] >= 25)
        {
            $xxx = '<em style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; color: #1b9eb2;">Supportive Member!</em>';
        }
        else
        {
            $xxx = "";
        }
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2" align="right" style="background: #323232; padding: 2px;"><div style="float: left;">'.$xxx.'</div>'.ucwords($row['poster']).' is '.$y.' | <a href="#quoteMessage" onClick="mQuoteMessage('.$row['id'].'); return false;">Quote Comment</a> | <a href="message,'.strtolower($row['poster']).'.html">Private Message</a></td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }

?>
<a name="checkComments"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var newComment = 'null';

  function makeRequest(url) {
    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
                http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                // See note below about this line
            }
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        if (!http_request) {
            return false;
        }
          http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { doContents(http_request); };
          http_request.open('GET', url, true);
          http_request.send(null);
    }

    function doContents(http_request) {

        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                newComment = http_request.responseText;
            if (newComment > 0) {
            document.getElementById('comCheck').innerHTML = 'There are ' + newComment + ' new comments. Would you like to?<br /><a href="#checkComments" onclick="SetDefault();">cancel</a> <a href="#checkComments" onclick="location.reload();">reload</a>';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('comCheck').innerHTML = 'No new comments found. <br /><a href="#checkComments" onclick="StartScan();">Try again</a>';
        }
            }
        }

    }
function SetDefault() {
   document.getElementById('comCheck').innerHTML = '<a href="#checkComments" onclick="StartScan();">Check for new comments</a>';
}
function StartScan() {
   document.getElementById('comCheck').innerHTML = 'Checking in progress, please wait...'; 
   <!-- Do The OnLine Scan -->
   makeRequest('com_update.php?id=<?=$id?>&current=<?=$comment_num?>');
}
</script>
<div style="border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; background: #242424; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; margin-bottom: 12px; text-align: center;" id="comCheck">
<a href="#checkComments" onclick="StartScan(); StartScan();">Check for new comments</a>
</div>
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($comment_list) != 0)
    {
        echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; background: #242424; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
              <div style="float: right; margin-top: 3px;">Current Page: '.$pg.' of '.$cc.'</div>';

        echo "<form name=\"pageForm\" method=\"get\" action=\"\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\">Go to page: <select name=\"pg\" onchange=\"document.location=this.value\" style='width: 40px;'>";

        for($i = 1; $i <= $cc; $i++)
        {
            if($i == $pg) {
                echo "<option value=\"comments,$id,$i.html\" selected=\"selected\">$i</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value=\"comments,$id,$i.html\">$i</option>";
            }
        }

        echo "</select> of $cc</form>";

        echo '</div>';
    }
        ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/exec/js/bbcode.js"></script>
<form name="textForm" id="textForm" method="post" action="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

        <?
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo '<legend style="color: #1b9eb2;">Comment</legend>';
        echo '<div style="padding-bottom: 4px;"></div>';
        echo '<strong>Body Message:</strong><br /><textarea class="ckeditor" name="textArea" id="textArea" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">';        
        echo '</textarea>';
        echo '<div style="margin-top: 8px;"></div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment" style="width: 88px;" /> ';
        echo '</form>';

        }
        else
        {

        $comment = trim($_POST['textArea']);


        if(!isset($comment) or empty($comment) or (strlen($comment) < 3) or (strlen($comment) > 3000))
        {

        echo '<fieldset style="padding: 4px; margin-top: 8px;">';
        echo '<legend style="color: #1b9eb2;">Comment</legend>';
        echo '<div style="padding-bottom: 4px; color: red;">The length of the entered comment was insufficient.</div>';
        echo '<strong>Body Message:</strong><br /><textarea class="ckeditor" name="textArea" id="textArea" style="width: 530px; height: 100px;">';    
        echo '</textarea>';
        echo '</fieldset>';
        echo '<div style="margin-top: 8px;"></div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment" style="width: 88px;" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Friends" style="width: 87px;" />';
        echo '</form>';

        }
        else
        {
                $date = date("l, F jS, Y \a\\t h:i:s A");
                $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);

        // ADVANCED BBCODE PREG PATTERNS - DON'T EVEN DARE TO MODIFY :)))
        $validUsername = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}";
        $validDate = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+,\s?[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]+,\s?\d+\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}";
        $validURL = ".*?";
        $quoteBBCodePattern = '/\[QUOTE=('.$validUsername.'),\s?('.$validDate.')\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/xs';
        $urlBBCodePattern = '/\[URL=('.$validURL.')\](.*?)\[\/URL\]/';
        // SIMPLE BBCODE REPLACE
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[(B|b|I|i|U|u)\]/", "<$1>", $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[\/(B|b|I|i|U|u)\]/", "</$1>", $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[(CODE|code)\](.*?)\[\/(CODE|code)\]/xs", '<div class="code">\\2</div>', $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[URL\]((http:\/\/)?(.*?))\[\/URL\]/", "<a href=\"http://\\3\">\\1</a>", $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[QUOTE\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/xs", "<div class=\"quote\">$1</div>", $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace("/\[SPOILER\](.*?)\[\/SPOILER\]/xs", "<div class=\"spoiler\" onclick=\"this.style.visibility='visible';\"><div>SPOILER</div>$1</div>", $comment);
        // ADVANCE BBCODE REPLACE
        $comment = preg_replace($quoteBBCodePattern, '<div class=\"quote\">$1 on $2<div class=\"under\">$3</div></div>', $comment);
        $comment = preg_replace($urlBBCodePattern, '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $comment);

                $comment = nl2br(addslashes($Std->parseEmoticons($comment)));
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (news_id, poster, date, comment) VALUES ('$id', '".ucwords($_SESSION['auth']['username'])."', '$date', '$comment')");
                mysql_query("UPDATE news SET comments = (comments + 1) WHERE id = '$id'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET posts = (posts + 1) WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['auth']['uid']}'");

                echo "<script style='text/javascript'>document.location='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'</script>";

     /*   echo '<form name="post_comment" id="post_comment" method="post" action="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">';
        echo '<fieldset style="padding: 4px;">';
        echo '<legend style="color: #456194;">Comment</legend>';
        echo '<div style="padding-bottom: 4px; color: green;">Your comment has been successfully submitted. <a href="comments,'.$news[0].','.$pages_num.'.html">Click here</a> to display your comment.</div>';
        echo '<strong>Body Message:</strong><br /><textarea name="comment_post" id="comment_post" style="width: 495px; height: 100px;">'.stripslashes($comment).'</textarea>';
        echo '</fieldset>';
        echo '<div style="margin-top: 8px;"></div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment" style="width: 100px;" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Friends" style="width: 88px;" /></div>';
        echo '</form>'; */

        }

        }


   //     echo "</div>";
    //echo "</div></div>";

        include ROOT . '/templates/' . $config['template_version'] . '/files/footer.php';

} else {
        header("Location: signin.html");
        exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: You should see ckeditor documentation its very detailed with examples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);`

this is the problem your converting all the < and > so they are stored in the db as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

the browser then shows the raw < and > instead of treating it as html.

REF: [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: @KatherineDeis *"When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer"* http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask